# Upgrading Mavericks --> Sierra

Tags: macos

I just tried to upgrade my OS from Mavericks to Sierra.
The app store shows that I have installed Sierra (see pic), but "about this mac" and the command line both say I still have 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

Am I missing a step?  Or is this a bug and how do I solve it?

[image]

Comment: You Downloaded it.  You didn't install it.  To install it, you need to to you Applications folder and launch it.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is the name of the thing I need to launch?
It does *say* installed (look at the pic).  What does that mean?

Comment: It says that a security update was installed. That Sierra banner is just an ad. The name of the app is "Install macOS Sierra.app" or something along those lines

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly confusing Apple UI-fail.

Since Allan is partly or basically correct:

> You downloaded it. You didn't install it. To install it, you need to
>   go to you Applications folder and launch it. – Allan Oct 31 '16 at 1:01

Seeing that the confusion persists:

> Can you be more specific? What is the name of the thing I need to
>   launch? It does say installed (look at the pic). What does that mean?
>   – user2429920 Oct 31 '16 at 4:04

Your picture displays "installed" for Sierra, alright.
You need to combine Allan's comment with the contents of this comment:

> The name of the app is "Install macOS Sierra.app" or
>   something along those lines – NoahL Oct 31 '16 at 4:16

That means: Your AppStore application has successfully installed the "Install macOS Sierra.app". That info is pictured in the banner you posted: you downloaded the installer completely and *the installer* is therefore marked as installed.

To actually install that new system as the system running your machine ("upgrade to Sierra") you indeed need to open the newly installed "Install macOS Sierra.app" in your Applications-folder. That will then guide you through the actual install after which your system will boot into Sierra.